# Django template request.user exists in model

Tags: django

models.py

```
class Universe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    Members_list = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', through='Members', blank=True)
    ...

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...


class Members(models.Model):
    uni = models.ForeignKey(Universe)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    ...
```

views.py

```
class UniverseDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Universe
    template_name = 'multiuniverse/universe_detail.html'
```

How can i check is request user is a member of this universe?

Something like

```
{{ if  Members.filter(uni==universe, profile.user==request.user).exists()  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In views.py:

```
class UniverseDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Universe
    template_name = 'multiuniverse/universe_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UniverseDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["member_exists"] = Members.objects.filter(uni==self.object(), profile.user=self.request.user).exists()
        return context
```

In your template:

```
{% if member_exists %}
     ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Error "'Universe' object is not callable". Gone after "uni=self.object()" => "uni=self.object"

Comment: Sorry. I meant `self.get_object()` but `self.object` works fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django [tamplatetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). In Templatetags create a function that will filter if the entry is a member or not using objects.filter, and place a templatetag filter in template to check.